# Count elements in a vector of vectors in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, count

If I have a matrix defined as:

```
(def m1 [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]])
```

How do I go about counting the vectors within the vector in clojure. I know that (count m1) will return 3 which is the number of vectors I have in the initial vector but I can't remember how to count the inner vectors (its been a very very long time since I've had to deal with any lisp dialect). Also I do not want to flatten the vector and then count it because I need to count the values separately (ie. I want to return 3, 3, 3 because each of the inner vectors have 3 elements. One last restriction I guess is that I want to do this without using map right away because I realized I can simply do (map count m1).

Comment: What do you mean "I want to do this without using map right away"? If you want to do things in a more roundabout, complex way, you can write a recursive function that does the same thing.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit: "I want to do this without using map."

```
(defn counts [vs]
  (loop [vs vs, cs []]
    (if (empty? vs)
      cs
      (recur (rest vs), (conj cs (count (first vs)))))))
```

Comment: `(reduce #(conj %1 (count %2)) [] [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]])` `[3 3 3]`

Comment: How does one use this function?

Answer (score 3):

That's actually very simple, just call:

```
(map count m1)
```

Or if you want to have your result also in vector:

```
(mapv count m1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually did some more googling and found that I could do that with map which is why I tossed in that ninja edit where I said I wanted to do it without map (yes I realize that means it will be very cumbersome)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `map`. It will apply count to each element in the vector and return a list of counts.

```
(def m1 [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]])
(map count m1)
=> (3 3 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! As I said on another comment I tossed in a ninja edit of saying I didn't want to use map.

Answer (score 0):

One answer quite good but use count.  Assume not using count and also not use map

((fn [lst] 
  (loop [l lst, n 0]
     (if (empty? l)
         n
         (recur (rest l) (inc n)))))'(1 2 3))